# Returning HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100)

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I am running my application on ruby on rails with phusion manager with nginx.I am getting below error.
**[Client 3-344] Returning HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100)**

Thanks in Advance

Tried increasing passenger_max_request_queue_size 1000; But it throwing as it available for Enterprise Edition.
and also tried using increasing 
    passenger_max_pool_size 15;
    passenger_min_instances 15;
But no use.

Comment: I am using ruby on rails with phusion manager with apache and I am getting same error.

[Client 2-10588] Returning HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100)